# Convert curl command line to php code

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send this json data via php, and not having the best luck.

```
curl --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' -X POST https://api.site.com --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"email": "mail@mail.com", "type": "note", "title": "title", "body": "Note Body"}'
```

Here's what I have:

```
     curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer <token>", "Content-Type: application/json"),
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.site.com",
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "email" => "mail@mail.com",
        "type" => "note",
        "title" => "alert",
        "body" => "body",
      ),
      CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like 
`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode( array(
        "email" => "mail@mail.com",
        "type" => "note",
        "title" => "alert",
        "body" => "body",
      )),`

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Just where I wasn't looking. I would upvote if I could.